# Tableau Target vs actual - data drop issue

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I am having a serious issue in tableau when comparing the current month value to the current month target. I am currently using data blending for this purpose. But this issue wont solve even if I use tableau relationship joining. I have 3 join clauses. Such as branch ID, Staff ID and Month/year. Pls see the below

Ex - january Target - 95,000

Actual - 126,000

But when 3  joining clauses created, its dropping data to 111,900.

the reason is in january,  even the allocated branch ID and month is matching, the other staff id clauses are dropping off.  That means even though the table A has all branches , staff ID's and date key, the txn table is having only one staff ID maching for January. If the 3 matches are not satisfying , data is dropping itself. How to solve this isseue? I need to show the total value of 126,000 infront of 95,000. not 111,900.

[image: Target]

[image: Actual]

[image: Target vs Actual]

Hope anyone can help.

Many thanks

Comment: Would you be able to add in a sample dataset (obviously with fake data) so we can get a sense of your data structure.  I think most of the answer depends on what the data looks like for the best answer to get the output you desire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This got achieved by a table unioning.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this could have been solved by changing the join type from an inner join to a right join.